# What kind of plant was Floris?

Tags: identification, houseplants, indoors, sedum

Does anyone know what kind of plant this is? (Me and my son called it Floris). This was my sons pet plant, he was quite attached to it. Also, is it normal for this kind of plant to just stop living? It was fine for a few years and then there was nothing I could do to stop it declining. I changed the soil, watered it properly and used plant food. I also tried a bunch of different places around the house but it went into decline and was no more. Any tips on keeping the next one alive would be very welcome.

[image: floris in better days]

Thanks.

Comment: Can't quite say what it is, but I'd put it in the general class of plants that you want to take occasional cuttings of (to root anew) as they indeed don't seem to grow old well - but their offspring normally do fine, and then their offspring's offspring, and...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floris appears to have been a low-growing sedum, perhaps related to [Sedum kamtschaticum](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91iPZoqqn-L._AC_SY879_.jpg). This species and its many cultivars is normally grown outside as a groundcover for sunny, rather dry spaces. It's hardy from zones 4–9.